# Complex types inside command

Tags: cqrs

I'm trying to apply CQRS in a pet project: in my example there is `Food` and `Course`.

A Course is composed by many item of different Food.

In my design I have those commands:

`AddFoodToCourse` `ChangeFoodQuantityInCourse` etc...

If I create a CourseCommandHandler I will get a ICourseRepository as dependency in order to modify courses but keeping commands simple I'll have CourseId and FoodId properties instead of Food.

In the handler I suppose to manage only Ids and get all the relevant data from a repository or not?

If I have understood correctly my app must follow this workflow:

Use `ReadModel` => Create a command and send to bus => `CommandHandler` consume command, operate with `domain object` and save objects with `repositories` => `Domain objects` raise events and publish into bus => `EventHandler` consume event and modify `ReadModel` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the handler I suppose to manage only Ids and get all the relevant
>   data from a repository or not?

Correct. The command handler is the place to inject repositories and other dependencies required to handle commands. As you stated, commands should reference entities using IDs not the entity itself. This is because the commands are meant to be serialized and passed across application boundaries. Your workflow is also correct. Take a look [here](http://abdullin.com/journal/2012/3/31/anatomy-of-distributed-system-a-la-lokad.html) for a more in-depth treatment on the subject.

Comment: So you tell me I have to inject each repository I need or I instead have to create a unique repository that allow entity load/save of any type?

Comment: Repository implementation is left up to you, though a typical CQRS repository is an event store, that can store events of various types keyed by a guid.